# Drupal hooks - registation

Tags: php, drupal

I have a Drupal website that I have integrated with a third party application. Currently I am required to execute 2-3 steps manually to ensure the new user account is integrated with my third party application. I can write a PHP application to execute these 2-3 steps. However I do not know how to execute this PHP file when a new user registers on Drupal.

Comment: [exec()](http://uk2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)??

Answer (score 1):

This is done via the [user hook](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_user/6). You can check for the different options from `$op` and do whatever you need to do. This needs to be done via a module, so read about how to create [your own modules](http://drupal.org/developing/modules).

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, Drupal permits to interact with its flow of operations via the so called "hooks". Whenever something relevant occurs, Drupal eventually fires these hook (they are functions, after all).

If you need to do something when a certain event occurs, you will create a module (third_party_integration.module, for example). In that module you'll write what you need to do when, for example, a new user is created.

In Drupal 7 the old hook_user() has been replaced with a whole set of more specific hooks: see http://api.drupal.org/api/search/7/hook_user_

The hook function must be called after your module name: for example: `third_party_integration_user_insert()`

The .module is just a plain PHP file, so you can add everything you need inside it (along with the actual hook function, of course).

Just remember to name EVERY functions in your module prepending your module name (with or without an prefixed _). This is just to play nice with other modules.